# How to get value of a key inside an object inside another object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable lets say x like this

```
x = {
  choice1: {
    choice: {
      name: "choice1",
      text: "abc",
      key: "key1"
    }
    isChecked: true
  },

  choice2: {
    choice: {
      name: "choice2",
      text: "def ",
      key: "key2"
    }
    isChecked: false
  }.

  choice3: {
    choice: {
      name: "choice3",
      text: "ijk ",
      key: "key3"
    }
    isChecked: false
  }

}
```

I want to get the key for which isChecked is true

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the values from your object and on this [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let x = {
  choice1:{ 
    choice: {name: "choice1", text: "abc", key: "key1"},
    isChecked: true
  },

  choice2:{
      choice: {name: "choice2", text: "def ", key: "key2"},
      isChecked: false
  },
  choice3:{
    choice: {name: "choice3", text: "ijk ", key:"key3"},
    isChecked: false
  }
};

let res = Object.values(x).filter(el => el.isChecked);
console.log(res);
```